# ComboBox Exception when items are not selected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox with several items and a button that have the focus of the Form.
The problem is that I need to change the `SelectedItem` or I will get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
comboBox.Text = "select";

try
{
    //if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    string some_str = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); // <-- Exception

    if (some_str.Contains("abcd"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
catch (Exception sel)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sel.Message);
}
```

Is there any way to avoid that? If I use `if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;`
 I don't get any error but my button also doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know what your trying to do or where that code is placed but have you tried this.ActiveControl = button;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `SelectedItem` is `null`, and you try to call `ToString()` on the `null` reference, you will get `NullReferenceException`.

You need to check for the null, before running `ToString()`:

```
string some_str = combBox.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); // <-- Exception

if (some_str.Contains("abcd"))
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if(comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    string some_str = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); // <-- Exception

    if (some_str.Contains("abcd"))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Please select an item");
}
```